# How to show mutliple date ranges (available dates) in daterangepicker and other dates should be disabled

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, daterangepicker

I am making an application in which I have to show multiple available dates(date ranges) in daterangepicker and other dates should be disable accordingly. Current I am using http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options and here is my example code.

```
$('#config-demo').daterangepicker({
"ranges": { 
            "Range1":  ["01/10/2017T07:37:40.792Z","01/10/2017T07:37:40.792Z"],
            "Range2": ["01/20/2017T07:37:40.792Z","01/30/2017T07:37:40.792Z"]
          },
 "linkedCalendars": false,
 "autoUpdateInput": true,
 "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
 "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
 "startDate": "01/10/2017",
 "endDate": "01/16/2017"
}, function(start, end, label) {
   console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '  to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

In this I have defined two date ranges and its not working for me. I want to show all available dates (date ranges) once in calendar.
Like

> 1st date range:- 01/10/2017 to 01/20/2017
>
> 2nd date range:- 01/25/2017 to 01/30/2017

These dates should be in one calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the functionality for the same here is an example code:-

```
var date_ranges = {

"staff_availabilities":[ 

    {"available_from":"2017/01/12","available_to":"2017/01/28","availibility_id":1},
    {"available_from":"2017/01/21","available_to":"2017/02/19","availibility_id":1}
]
};

var i = 0;

var f_data = [];
var obj = {};

$.each(date_ranges.staff_availabilities, function( index, value ) {

   var start_date = value.available_from;
   var end_date = value.available_to;
   var start_date_range = moment(start_date, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").format('MMMM D, Y');
   var end_date_range = moment(end_date, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").format('MMMM D, Y');
   obj[start_date_range+" - "+end_date_range] = [value.available_from , value.available_to];

   i++;

});

$('#config-demo').daterangepicker({
        "ranges":obj,
        "linkedCalendars": false,
        "autoUpdateInput": true,
        "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
        "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        },
        "startDate": mini_date,
        "endDate": max_date
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
    });
```